# Pre-release checklist

Tags: cocoa, xcode

I built an 10.6+ only app, I tested it in 32-bit and 64-bit mode and everything works (or at least I couldn't find anything wrong).

I need help with the actual release build of the app.

What settings should I keep an eye out for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote a free tool to [validate your Info.plist](http://www.jwwalker.com/pages/infoplistchecker.html) file.

Also, you should sign your code.  (If you're not familiar with that, look up the Code Signing Guide in the Xcode documentation viewer.)

Answer (score 1):

I wrote [a Mac app checklist](http://boredzo.org/blog/archives/2007-03-18/mac-app-checklist) a few years ago. Mostly still accurate today, although I now use [Mercurial](http://mercurial.selenic.com/) instead of Subversion and [Opacity](http://likethought.com/opacity/) instead of PostScript.